# change TextView GRAVITY in getView method of CustomListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I have a customListAdapter with three textviews what I want is that when certain condition is met GRAVITY of all three textviews should be reversed as shown in comments in the code. I am only posting customAdapter not remaining code as it is irrevalent.

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<NewsItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<NewsItem> listData)     {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout,      null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.headlineView = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (some condition true){
   // reverse GRAVITY of all TEXTVIEWS
  }
    holder.headlineView.setText(listData.get(position).getHeadline());

    holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " +      listData.get(position).getReporterName());
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(listData.get(position).getDate());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView headlineView;
    TextView reporterNameView;
    TextView reportedDateView;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you simply want to change the gravity of the text views?

Comment: yes when certain condition is met..

Comment: Have you tried `setGravity(int)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
holder.headlineView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
holder.reporterNameView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

in your condition set the gravity:

```
if (some condition true){
holder.headlineView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you can change the gravity programmatically:

```
if (some condition true){
   // reverse GRAVITY of all TEXTVIEWS
   holder.headlineView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
   holder.reporterNameView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT| Gravity.TOP);
   holder.reportedDateView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT| Gravity.BOTTOM);
}
```